# Do i need to install mono on every Linux PC to run .NET application on Linux platform?

Tags: .net, linux, mono

I have one sample .exe file which was developed in windows as .NET application. Now , I can run the same application on my Linux Machine using mono command.

So, Now i want to give the separate Binary to our client which can be run on both Windows as well as Linux platform.

So, .net based windows application can be run on any other windows based PC without installing .NET.

Is there any same in Linux platform to compile same .NET application using gmcs command and run on any Linux PC without installing mono which is required to run .NET application?

How can i give the separate binary which can be run only on Linux PC because that binary is based on my Linux driver as well as my shared object (.so) file?

Answer (score 2):

"can I run a mono application on a machine that doesn't have mono installed": no; the same as you can't run a java application on a machine that doesn't have java installed.

And at the same time (to both): yes. There *are* tools that attempt to make this work, but they tend to be fiddly and a bit unreliable. However, it should also be noted that several (not all, by any means) distros ship with mono by default.

Comment: so, you mean that most of the Linux machine is already installed with mono as default package. Right?

Comment: @RiteshPrajapati I did not say "most"; you will have to make your own enquiry as to mono install base. Ubuntu does include it, as a single example.

Comment: @RiteshPrajapati No, only a few distros installed it by default.